# Jquery and Hide a div on a click

Tags: jquery, html, click, hide

i have a little problem with JQuery.

Well, i have a  and i want to hide this div when an user click in a zone that is not in the  like the "notifications" behavior in facebook.

The solution that i found is to use jQuery.live() method but i think there is a better way to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming:

```
<div class="notification">You have 3 new messages</div>
```

use:

```
$(document).click(function(evt) {
  if ($(this).closest("div.notification").length == 0) {
    $("div.notification").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Basically this listens to all clicks. If one is received that doesn't occur inside a notification div it fades them out.

Comment: What happens if the click is made on `div.notification` itself?

Comment: @rahul had to make a slight correction for that case (`parents()` to `closest()`) but basically it won't fade them out if clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but, the :

```
$(this).closest("div.notification").length == 0)
```

always return me 0 (even if i click in the div), so the div is always hidden.

This is my code :

```
$(document).click(function(evt) {
        if ($(this).closest("div#show_notif").length==0)
            $("div#show_notif").fadeOut();
});
```

And the html :

```
<div id="click_show_notif" onclick="$('div#show_notif').show();"><img src="http://'+STATIC_SERVER+'/images/notif.png" /><div id="show_notif"></div>
```

There is something that i forgot ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#click_show_notif").live('click',function(e) {
    $("#show_notif").show();
    return false;
});

$('body').live('click',function(e) {
    if ($(this).closest("div#show_notif").length==0) {
        $("div#show_notif").hide();
    }
});
```