# Hide an image on click

Tags: jquery

I have been struggling to figure out why my code is not working properly. 
I am working on a browser implementation of the game minesweeper, and am trying to get an image to hide() when the element is clicked. 
My html is as follows...

```
<img id="61" class="reveal" width="30px" height="30px" style="position:absolute;" src="img/tile.ico">
```

and my jquery looks like this...

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $(".reveal").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("id").hide();
     });
  });
```

The problem seems to be my trying to grab the element id using $(this).attr("id").

Comment: See also similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711020/jquery-and-hide-a-div-on-a-click/2711199#2711199

Comment: why are you adding `$(this).attr("id").hide();`? do you need the ID for some reason? if not, you should just do this: `$(this).hide();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are trying to target another element, simply hide `this` (which will be the `class="reveal"` element clicked):

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $(".reveal").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
     });
  });
```

The problem with your code is that `attr` returns a string, which you are then trying to run `hide()` on :)

Note: A better DOM-ready shortcut is simply:

```
  $(function() {
      $(".reveal").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
     });
  });
```

Comment: Awesome. I was not expecting an answer that fast! This works for me.

Comment: @user3468711: fast is the name of the game here (*the quick or the point-less*) :)

Comment: @user3468711 Yes it's know as *Fastest Gun in the West*. In problems like these most people can look at it and know the solution. But only the person who answers first gets the points.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek: Indeed. I used to write answers like this under-appreciated one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801546/silverlight-rotate-scale-a-bitmap-image-to-fit-within-rectangle-without-croppi/6802332#6802332 but not so much nowadays :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to hide the attribute with attr('id'), not the image. Use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".reveal").click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
```

to hide the image.

Comment: A correct answer, but would be better with some explanatory information as to what was wrong.

Comment: @CodeGodie that's correct. We posted it at the same time ;)

Comment: 7 seconds earlier... but who's counting :)